# BMR Protocol Explanation

Tags: multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

The idea of n-1 parties being garblers and 1 party being evaluator is not clear to me.  Can I get an explanation of how the BMR protocol runs stage by stage with an example.

I guess the keys to each wire is concatenation of the keys from every garbler, however what's the need for permutation bit?

How is the security of the protocol ensured?

Comment: You can start with section 3.5 of the [Pragmatic MPC](https://securecomputation.org/docs/pragmaticmpc.pdf) book.